# Trying to use sin() method in Python Clifford Algebra package

Tags: python

According to the API document the MultiVector has a method called sin().  This made no sense to me.  How can sine be unary operator?  It's binary in nature.  So I tried excuting it, which as expected did not work.

```
import clifford as cf

layout, blades = cf.Cl(4)
locals().update(blades)
e1.sin()
```

Here's the Clifford source code.  Sure looks to me like it's there.

```
class MultiVector(object):
...

    def sin(self) -> 'MultiVector':
        return taylor_expansions.sin(self)
```

So what do they have in mind with "sin()" and numerous other similar procedures?  What use is it and how is it supposed to be invoked?

Comment: what is e1 in your context?

Comment: e1 is the first basis blade.  A blade is of the class MultiVector.  I can print e1 out so I know it is defined.